# Pushing Object to an empty array where the value of one Object key is based on the empty array, with a function

Tags: javascript, arrays, oop, object, crud

I have an assignment that I need help with. (I tried to translate this assignment from my native language, so I hope it is still understandable)

The assignment is a CRUD function problem, which is as follows:

1. create an object template for the employee (id, name, age)
2. create a function that receives an object argument as a parameter
3. the output should be success (boolean)

Here is what the teacher gave us to start with:

```
let employee = [];

// create blueprint here

// create -> insert data of new employee. receives parameter object
function create(employee_data){
    // write your logic here
}

create(new Employee(employee[employee.length-1].id + 1, "Vincent", 25));

//output: success(boolean)
```

Right now I haven't created the create- function because I want to try it manually first. Yet I still don't know how because there's always an error in inputting the id since it is based on the empty employee []

```
let employee = [];

//=========== TEMPLATE 
class Employee {
  constructor(id, nama, age) {
    this.id = id;
    this.nama = nama;
    this.age = age;
  }
}
//=========== TEMPLATE 

console.log(employee);

employee.push(
  new Employee(
    employee[employee.length-1].id + 1,
    "Vincent",
    25
  )
);
console.log(employee[0]);
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: I assume you are supposed to fill in this array at your own discretion

Comment: The `employee` array is empty initially and accessing `id` of undefined will throw an error. You can pass this `(employee[employee.length-1]?.id ?? 0) + 1` as the first parameter. OR you can pass `1` the first time and then onwards, you can use the `employee[employee.length-1].id + 1` bit

Comment: `employee[employee.length-1].id` will return `undefined` when you push first.

Answer (score 0):

Try using employee.length + 1 as id of the newly created employee object

Refer below

```js
let employee = [];


//=========== TEMPLATE 
class Employee {
  constructor(id, nama, age) {
    this.id = id;
    this.nama = nama;
    this.age = age;
  }
}
//=========== TEMPLATE 

function create(employee_data){
  // write your logic here
  employee.push(employee_data)
  return true;
}

const newEmployee = new Employee(employee.length+1, "Vincent", 25)
create(newEmployee);


//console.log(employee);

// employee.push(
//   new Employee(
//     employee[employee.length-1].id + 1,
//     "Vincent",
//     25
//   )
// );
console.log(employee[0]);
```